# Hibernate JPA EntityManager.createQuery() performance

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a query which has 2 'in' Clauses. First in clause takes around 125 values and second in clause of query takes around 21000 values. Its implemented using JPA `CriteriaBuilder`.

Query itself executes very fast and return results within seconds. Only problem is `entityManager.createQuery(CriteriaQuery)` takes around 12-13 minutes to return.

I search all over SO, all the threads are related to performance of `Query.getResultList`. None of them discuss about performance of `entityManager.createQuery(CriteriaQuery)`. If you have seen such behavior earlier, please let me know, how to resolve it.

My JDK version is 1.7. Dependency version of javaee-api is 6.0. Application is deployed on JBOSS EAP 6.4. But that's not the concern as of now, as I am testing my code using junit using `EntityManager` connected to actual Oracle database. If you require more information, kindly let me know.

Comment: Well JPA is only an API, there is an implementation under there which might be the source of the problem. Hibernate? OpenJPA? EclipseLink?

Comment: have you tried to profile the application (YourKit or JProfiler or any other...)?

Comment: @Gimby: Well, we are using all APIs from javax.persistence.* which are available in java-api-6.0 jar. We are not using any hibernate specific APIs. My application is deployed on JBOSS EAP 6.4.

Comment: @hunter: I didnt profile my application. This is basically simple code and I know the line on which my code is stuck. its where I create TypedQuery object using entityManager.createQuery()

Comment: No my point is , if it is Hibernate then lot of hibernate stuffs will be called when you execute this method, ex: it will try to create HQLQueryPlan and put it in to a cache, so if you can CPU  profile your application then you can understand which part consumes the time. then we can study the code and understand whether the problem is caused because of huge number of IN clause elements or not

Comment: 21000 values is insanely high. Oracle for example will just reject yoru query if it has more than 1000 values in the in clause. Can't you use a join instead? Or put all those values in a temporary table and join over that temporary table?

Comment: @JBNizet: I have logic to create multiple OR clause in case number of elements for in clause increases beyond 1000.

Comment: Yes, but then you can hit other limits, like the length of the query, depending on the database. This strategy looks wrong to me.

Comment: @hunter: Let me try that.

Comment: @JBNizet: I don't have any control over database. I can not create/delete any tables at runtime. My schema has only read only access. It is possible to implement something like temporary tables using JPA in java?

Comment: I wonder if switching to using a native query rather than JPQL would make any difference in this case. Worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that, having single query with 21 IN clauses (each with 1000 expressions) and all combined with OR clauses, made query run slower. I tried another approach of executing every IN Clause as a part of separate query. So these 21 individual queries performed better overall.

Another issue I observed was that Query with CriteriaBuilder was slow when result set is huge (something like 20K rows in result set). I solved this issue by adding query hint to my typed query:

```
TypedQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.fetchSize", 5000);
```

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

A hybrid approach is to dynamically create a query and then save it as a named query in the entity manager factory.

At that point it becomes just like any other named query that may have been declared statically in metadata. While this may seem like a good compromise, it turns out to be useful in only a few specific cases. The main advantage it offers is if there are queries that are not known until runtime, but then reissued repeatedly. Once the dynamic query becomes a named query it will only bear the cost of processing once.

It is implementation-specific whether that cost is paid when the query is registered as a named query, or deferred until the first time it is executed.

A dynamic query can be turned into a named query by using the

```
EntityManagerFactory addNamedQuery()
```

Keep us informed by the result and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Code in Hibernate is not expected to be used for binding lots of params:

```
        for ( ImplicitParameterBinding implicitParameterBinding : parameterMetadata.implicitParameterBindings() ) {
            implicitParameterBinding.bind( jpaqlQuery );
        }
```

Unfortunately you need to find different approach if you want to do something similar.